# Serializing rust HashMap with custom hash function

Tags: serialization, rust, hashmap

I'm trying to serialize a rust HashMap with a custom hash function applying `bincode::serialize_into(writer, cache)?;` where  `cache` is a struct-object defined as following:

```
use std::hash::{BuildHasherDefault, Hasher};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub(crate) struct Cache<S>
where
    S: Default + Hasher,
{
    records: HashMap<DNA, Mapping, BuildHasherDefault<S>>,
}
```

When compiling I receive an error `the trait 'cli::_::_serde::Serialize' is not implemented for 'S'` referring to the `cache` variable.

As described in this [issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/369) serialization for custom hash functions (in my case [FnvHasher](https://doc.servo.org/fnv/struct.FnvHasher.html)) should exist requiring only to implement the BuildHasher trait.
That trait is already implemented by [BuildHasherDefault](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/struct.BuildHasherDefault.html) which is used to create a `BuildHasher` instance.

Edit:
To illustrate the issue I've create a [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a1d25db65cdeb72df1b0cd1fc0da131) (as bincode is not available in playground I used serde_json instead).
As the example shows it is possible to create and serialize a HashMap `custom_hashmap` with custom hash-function (in this case `FnvHasher`).
But this does not work for a Cache-object `cache` wrapping a HashMap with a custom hash-function. In that case the compiler asks for adding the `Serialize` trait which does not exist for the `FnvHasher`

Comment: Implement `serde::Serialize` on whatever `S` is. Also refrain from adding trait bounds on struct definition, but if for some reason you must, then add `Serialize` bound onto `S` there so you get an error when you try to create a `Cache<S>` but `S` isn't `Serialize`. And even then it would be better to add it on `impl<S: Serialize> Cache<S>`, assuming you use `Cache::new` to create your struct...

Comment: Then either implement Serialize on it yourself, or serialize in a way that does not care what hasher is used, given that ordering of KVP's is not important when you're using a hash table.

Comment: In a more specific case `S` could be [FnvHasher](https://docs.rs/fnv/1.0.7/fnv/struct.FnvHasher.html) which does not implement `Serialize`.
Based on that [issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/369) it looks like custom hash functions which do not implement `Serialize` (e.g. fnv) are supported.
So it should not be necessary to implement that trait or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just want you to write: `where
    S: Default + Hasher + Serialize` ?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example that reproduces the issue? I tried and the code I came up with [compiles on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d355f3c94ca61ebeddfaac07313b8cbc).

Comment: @user4815162342 I have [extended your playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a1d25db65cdeb72df1b0cd1fc0da131) as the issue occurs when serializing.

In the example I've created a HashMap `custom_hashmap` with a custom hash function. Additionally, there is a Cache `custom_cache` with exactly the same HashMap (and hash function) . While it is possible to serialize `custom_hashmap` it is not for `custom_cache` as the compiler asks to add `Serialize` for S. But I can not do so as it is not implemented by `FnvHasher`.

Comment: Please also edit the question to include the updated example and the explanation from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Define custom bounds on the problematic field as documented [here](https://serde.rs/attr-bound.html).

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub(crate) struct Cache<S>
where
    S: Default + Hasher,
{
    #[serde(bound(
        serialize = "HashMap<DNA, Mapping, BuildHasherDefault<S>>: Serialize",
        deserialize = "HashMap<DNA, Mapping, BuildHasherDefault<S>>: Deserialize<'de>"
    ))]
    records: HashMap<DNA, Mapping, BuildHasherDefault<S>>,
}
```

[Full fixed playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93acb360c927aacf422d8fcc76a16fa0)